# How do I block ips from accessing my sever with UFW

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, firewall, ufw

I want to try to block my computer's IP (**192.168.0.3**) as a test from accessing anything on my server, and more importantly, my website, when I use `ufw deny 192.168.0.3` it says `Rule added`, After running the command I can still access https://sturtz.ml, https://search.sturtz.ml and https://social.sturtz.ml from the computer that it says is blocked access via ufw and I can also run ssh from the same computer
The output of `ufw status` is

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
10000                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
53                         ALLOW       192.168.0.0/24            
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Bind9                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
442                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
53                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Anywhere                   DENY        192.168.0.3               
192.168.0.3                DENY        Anywhere                  
10000 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Bind9 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Apache (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
442 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
53 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Here is the last 20 lines of the UFW log

```
May 20 09:51:44 sturtz kernel: [ 3229.347594] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=94.102.51.28 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=244 ID=61523 PROTO=TCP SPT=58116 DPT=5433 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May 20 09:52:19 sturtz kernel: [ 3264.798448] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=185.137.234.205 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x20 TTL=244 ID=47386 PROTO=TCP SPT=56127 DPT=3404 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May 20 09:52:37 sturtz kernel: [ 3282.656024] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=89.248.172.101 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=244 ID=38261 PROTO=TCP SPT=42467 DPT=14789 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May 20 09:52:43 sturtz kernel: [ 3288.586744] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=185.176.27.174 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=243 ID=1014 PROTO=TCP SPT=44184 DPT=44416 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May 20 09:52:45 sturtz kernel: [ 3290.519284] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=89.165.142.219 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x20 TTL=51 ID=6563 PROTO=TCP SPT=20908 DPT=8000 WINDOW=19124 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May 20 09:53:19 sturtz kernel: [ 3324.501803] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=117.198.96.184 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=117 ID=11095 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=54603 DPT=8728 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May 20 09:53:31 sturtz kernel: [ 3335.943548] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=162.244.80.191 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=244 ID=23596 PROTO=TCP SPT=49361 DPT=3389 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May 20 09:54:00 sturtz kernel: [ 3365.682223] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=162.244.80.191 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=244 ID=59247 PROTO=TCP SPT=49361 DPT=34567 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May 20 09:54:12 sturtz kernel: [ 3377.812730] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=82.77.216.217 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=118 ID=38829 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=54794 DPT=8291 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May 20 09:54:15 sturtz kernel: [ 3380.798075] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=82.77.216.217 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=118 ID=38831 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=54794 DPT=8291 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May 20 09:54:36 sturtz kernel: [ 3401.409066] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=162.244.80.191 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=246 ID=48836 PROTO=TCP SPT=49361 DPT=5984 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May 20 09:54:55 sturtz kernel: [ 3420.872766] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=89.248.168.217 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=57 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=244 ID=54321 PROTO=UDP SPT=46481 DPT=6481 LEN=37 
May 20 09:55:15 sturtz kernel: [ 3440.636976] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=162.244.80.191 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=246 ID=5095 PROTO=TCP SPT=49361 DPT=88 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May 20 09:55:38 sturtz kernel: [ 3463.596782] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=185.156.73.65 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=244 ID=22233 PROTO=TCP SPT=52105 DPT=5606 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May 20 09:56:06 sturtz kernel: [ 3491.162718] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=185.209.0.32 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=241 ID=33653 PROTO=TCP SPT=41187 DPT=13131 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May 20 09:56:21 sturtz kernel: [ 3506.874677] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=162.244.80.191 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=246 ID=2446 PROTO=TCP SPT=49361 DPT=5555 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May 20 09:56:39 sturtz kernel: [ 3524.649919] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=162.244.80.191 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=246 ID=42155 PROTO=TCP SPT=49361 DPT=1080 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May 20 09:57:03 sturtz kernel: [ 3548.892867] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=183.136.225.45 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=108 ID=64518 PROTO=TCP SPT=20801 DPT=8089 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May 20 09:57:15 sturtz kernel: [ 3560.579357] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=162.244.80.191 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=246 ID=44530 PROTO=TCP SPT=49361 DPT=60001 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May 20 09:57:38 sturtz kernel: [ 3583.308522] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s25 OUT= MAC=00:23:24:08:58:1f:00:24:7b:16:93:98:08:00 SRC=162.244.80.191 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=246 ID=64173 PROTO=TCP SPT=49361 DPT=85 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly? Did you read the man page section about rule order?

Comment: Yes, I did and it did not make the much sense,